# OperationCanceledException VS TaskCanceledException when task is canceled

Tags: c#, .net, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library

The following code creates a task which is being canceled. `await` expression (case 1) throws `System.OperationCanceledException` while synchronous `Wait()` (case 2) throws `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException` (wrapped in `System.AggregateException`).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program.MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        using(var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            const int cancelationCheckTimeout = 100;

            var task = Task.Run(
                async () => 
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        Console.Write(".");
                        await Task.Delay(cancelationCheckTimeout);  
                    }
                }, 
                cancellationTokenSource.Token
            );

            var cancelationDelay = 10 * cancelationCheckTimeout;
            cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(cancelationDelay);

            try
            {
                await task; // (1)
                //task.Wait(); // (2) 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine($"Task.IsCanceled: {task.IsCanceled}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Task.IsFaulted: {task.IsFaulted}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Task.Exception: {((task.Exception == null) ? "null" : task.Exception.ToString())}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Case 1 output:

```
..........System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
   at Program.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<<MainAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Program.<MainAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
Task.IsCanceled: True
Task.IsFaulted: False
Task.Exception: null
```

Case 2 output:

```
..........System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Program.<MainAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.<---

Task.IsCanceled: True
Task.IsFaulted: False
Task.Exception: null
```

**Why `System.AggregateException` in the 2nd case doesn't contain `System.OperationCanceledException` as an inner exception?**

I know that `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` throws `OperationCanceledException` and we can see that in both cases `Task` gets to canceled (not faulty) state.

This puzzles me because canceling a method from .NET API produces consistent behaviour in both cases - canceled task throws only `TaskCanceledException`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program.MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        using(var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

            var task = Task.Delay(1000, token);
            cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(100);

            try
            {
                await task; // (1)
                //task.Wait(); // (2)
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine($"Task.IsCanceled: {task.IsCanceled}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Task.IsFaulted: {task.IsFaulted}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Task.Exception: {((task.Exception == null) ? "null" : task.Exception.ToString())}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Case 1 output:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Program.<MainAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
Task.IsCanceled: True
Task.IsFaulted: False
Task.Exception: null
```

Case 2 output:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Program.<MainAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.<---

Task.IsCanceled: True
Task.IsFaulted: False
Task.Exception: null
```

Comment: Does it matter? `TaskCanceledException` is a derived class of `OperationCanceledException` so if you did `catch(OperationCanceledException e)` you would catch both types of exceptions. The only piece of information you loose is the `TaskCanceledException.Task` property.

Comment: I agree but I was more curious about the reasons for introducing/using `TaskCanceledException` when there is already `OperationCanceledException`.

Comment: The reason for introducing it is when you have some cases you are able to grab the context of the Task that was canceled so in those situations where you can it throws the more derived form that includes the Task. `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` is generically written, it does not know it is inside of a Task so it raises the more general exception without the Task property.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The difference here comes from using `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`. This method checks for cancellation and if requested throws `OperationCanceledException` specifically and not `TaskCanceledException` (understandable as `CancellationToken` isn't exclusive to the [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)). You can look at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationToken.cs,466) and see that it calls this method:

```
private void ThrowOperationCanceledException()
{
    throw new OperationCanceledException(Environment.GetResourceString("OperationCanceled"), this);
}
```

"Regular" cancellation though will indeed generate a `TaskCanceledException`. You can see that by cancelling the token **before** the task had a chance to start running:

```
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
var task = Task.Run(() => { }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
try
{
    await task; 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine($"Task.IsCanceled: {task.IsCanceled}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Task.IsFaulted: {task.IsFaulted}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Task.Exception: {((task.Exception == null) ? "null" : task.Exception.ToString())}");
}
```

Output:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Sandbox.Program.<MainAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
Task.IsCanceled: True
Task.IsFaulted: False
Task.Exception: null
```

Traditional .Net methods usually don't use `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` for async API as this is only appropriate when offloading work to another thread. These methods are for inherently asynchronous operations so cancellation is monitored using `CancellationToken.Register` (or the internal `InternalRegisterWithoutEC`).

Comment: I observed cancelling .NET methods (e.g. `Task.Delay()` or `FileStream.WriteAsync()`) and noticed that they all throw `TaskCanceledException` if canceled (via CancellationToken which is not exclusive to the TPL as you said). It sort of makes sense that cancelling Task itself (not the callback it wraps) throws `TaskCanceledException` as in your example above. But why `FileStream.WriteAsync()` doesn't throw  `OperationCanceledException`? Could you please expand on `offloading work to another thread` reasoning?

Comment: @BojanKomazec `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` throws `OperationCanceledException`. You only call that method when you have code running that periodically needs to check for cancellation. Built-in async API doesn't do that, as it's synchronous. It doesn't hold a thread that does something in a loop. So there's no code running to call  `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

Comment: @BojanKomazec `Task.Delay` for example, creates a promise task, starts a timer that will complete the task when the timeout ends and registers a delegate to cancel the task on the token with `CancellationToken.Register`. It then returns the task and that's it. There's nowhere to call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested `.

Comment: I understand now that there is no additional thread involved but still, why did .NET async API implementers choose to introduce new exception type `TaskCanceledException`, why they didn't reuse `OperationCanceledException`? Async API callers will anyway be expecting `OperationCanceledException` and `OperationCanceledException` does not need a separate thread or `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in order to be thrown.

Comment: @BojanKomazec that's a different question. TCE was introduced with TPL in .net 4.0 long before they added async API. They could have reused the exception but it's reasonable to add another specific type for tasks even if it can't be used for every single usage around tasks.

Answer (score 23):

`TaskCanceledException` inherits from `OperationCanceledException`. So it least there is a little consitency.

```
if( ex is OperationCanceledException)
{
...
}
```