# C# exception on cancellation of background task

Tags: c#, async-await, task, httpclient, cancellation

I have a simple HttpClient downloading solution where I need to support cancel download.
Download itself works perfectly, however when I attempt to cancel download, I receive following exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SslStream'

My code is the following:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) };

DownloadButton.Click += async (s, e) => {
    var LocalPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "index-5200-00.fits");
    if (!File.Exists(LocalPath)) {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(LocalPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            using (var msg = await client.GetAsync(link1, cts.Token))
                await msg.Content.CopyToAsync(fs, cts.Token);
        Status = "Downloaded!";
    }
};

CancelButton.Click += (s, e) => {
    if (!cts.IsCancellationRequested) cts.Cancel();
};
```

Question is, how to properly handle the download cancellation?

Comment: Might it help if you drop the cancellationToken on `client.GetAsync`? You don't what to cancel that. At least, not with the cancel button. It will be disposed anyhow

Comment: As a side note the `if (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)` is redundant. In case the `cts` is already canceled, the `cts.Cancel()` will have no effect (it will be a no-op).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this code. It works exactly as expected:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) };

DownloadButton.Click += async (s, e) => {
    var LocalPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "index-5200-00.fits");
    if (!File.Exists(LocalPath)) {
        try {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(LocalPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(link1, cts.Token))
                await stream.CopyToAsync(fs, cts.Token);
            Text = "Downloaded!";
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException) {
            if (File.Exists(LocalPath)) File.Delete(LocalPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
};

CancelButton.Click += (s, e) => {
    cts.Cancel();
};
```

Comment: Probably best to do `catch (OperationCanceledException) {` instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34359530/14868997

Answer (score 0):

Add a try before any async call first, then,

Be sure to register a callback:
cancellationToken.Register(client.CancelAsync);

then when running the method await msg.Content.CopyToAsync(fs, cts.Token);

On the catch block you can handle the cancelation as follows:

```
catch (WebException ex) when (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
            {
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
            }               
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
            }
```

Comment: How wil this catch the objectdisposedexception? The token should already be registered of you pass it to GetAsync.

Comment: since you are using the using statement which disposes once the operation inside is done. The response is yes, just be sure to bubble up exceptions from most specific to generic.